# Lowest cost Windows VPS hosting?

Tags: windows, hosting, vps

For a while, I thought I'd host stuff at home because I can do whatever I want.  However, hurricane Ike knocked out my power for a week, and I've finally realized this situation won't work.

I have extremely low traffice websites (20 visitors/day), so I don't need tons of CPU or bandwidth.  What cheap options are there for VPS hosting that will give me flexiblity to do what I need to configure my server, but not cost very much.

Comment: Server pricing information goes out of date monthly, voting for close as too localized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RapidVPS offers windows hosting. $29,99/month

https://www.rapidvps.com/index.php?page=Hosting.Windows.Specs

I am a customer of their linux vps hosting and have had zero problems.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Applied Innovations](http://www.appliedi.net/) for my .NET hosting. They seem to have cheap VPS as well.

I've never noticed a downtime,and their billing and support has been reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Check out KickAssVPS I have had a Windows VPS with them for over a year now.

http://www.kickassvps.com/

I have the $35 package which is
960 MB RAM
10GB Space
100GB Transfer

Answer (score 0):

http://www.ajkservers.co.uk

Get high quality VPS from them :) They support linux.